# How to open HSQLDB resource inside jar (read-only) after modularisation using DriverManager?

Tags: java, hsqldb, java-platform-module-system, modularization

The internal read only database is stored in its own resource-only-jar file. After modularisation the database file cannot be found by the DriverManager resulting in the following error message.

```
FATAL : 09:13:32 (830) - could not reopen database
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database does not exists: /database/prodsoft
```

I am converting our company's application from JDK8 using ANT to JDK11 using modularisation and Maven. It is developed with Eclipse. Many problems already have been fixed but for this one I cannot find a solution on my own.

I already tried to move the database files from its own project to the maven resource folder of the project *Kernel* where it is used.
I also tried to ***opens*** database; (the resource folder) in the module-info.java of the *Kernel*-project.

The database files *prodsoft.properties* and *prodsoft.script* are now located in

```
src/main/resources/database/
```

The Class that runs the DriverManager is

```
src/main/java/de/benthin/dataaccess/DatabaseReadOnly
```

The *hsqldb-2.4.1.jar*-driver has been found successfully and is used by the DriverManager.

```
// ApplicationProperties.DATABASE_CONNECTION = "jdbc:hsqldb:res:database/prodsoft"

db_con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        properties.getValue(ApplicationProperties.DATABASE_CONNECTION),
        properties.getValue(ApplicationProperties.DATABASE_USER),
        properties.getValue(ApplicationProperties.DATABASE_PASSWORD)
    );

db_con.setAutoCommit(true);
db_con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
db_con.setReadOnly(true);
```

Comment: Have you tried `"jdbc:hsqldb:res:database.prodsoft"`?

Comment: Just did. `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database does not exists: /database.prodsoft`. But as database is a folder and the database consist of two files, I think the file formats are handled by the driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at http://hsqldb.org/ where version 2.5 was announced for the future. I think that version 2.4.1 is only compatible until Java 10 but I did not test my case with Java 9 and 10.

As workaround I will export the database at program start and delete it after usage.
As soon as the new version of the hsqldb driver is available I will update this question.